# Error when send a notification with FireBase Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, firebase

I try to follow this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

In class named MyFireBaseMessaging this method:

```
private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json) {
        Log.e(TAG, "push json: " + json.toString());

        try {
            JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

            title = data.getString("title");
            message = data.getString("message");
            isBackground = data.getBoolean("is_background");
            imageUrl = data.getString("image");
            timestamp = data.getString("timestamp");
            payload = data.getJSONObject("payload");

            Log.e(TAG, "title: " + title);
            Log.e(TAG, "message: " + message);
            Log.e(TAG, "isBackground: " + isBackground);
            Log.e(TAG, "payload: " + payload.toString());
            Log.e(TAG, "imageUrl: " + imageUrl);
            Log.e(TAG, "timestamp: " + timestamp);


            if (!NotificationUtilities.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
                // pusho il messaggio se l'app è in attiva
                Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
                pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

                // avvio il suono di notifica
                NotificationUtilities notificationUtilities =
                        new NotificationUtilities(getApplicationContext());
                notificationUtilities.playNotificationSound();
            } else {
                // se l'app è in background, visualizzo la notifica nello spazio notifiche
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);

                // verifico se ho un immagine da visualizzare
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
                    showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp,
                            resultIntent);
                } else {
                    // se ho un immagine la visualizzo col messaggio
                    showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(getApplicationContext(), title, message,
                            timestamp, resultIntent, imageUrl);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Handle Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

When my app is in background I do not receive notifications but in the log I can see this message: "Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference" by second catch
I send message from PHP Backend like the tutorial,how could I solve?
Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Please attach your log files. And did you had gcm projects from before or you are creating a new one? If you are creating a new one then it will not work because officially now only firebase is supported for new users. Plus you do realize that many tutorials on androidhive are outdated like this one. AndroidHive is fantastic for beginners but Ravi Tammada is too busy to update all tutorials.